# Is this statement regarding polynomials true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, polynomials

I have a hunch that the following statement (that I came up with) is true given that any $n-1$-degree polynomial is completely determined by $n$ points.

However, I am not sure how to go about with the proof ... Any help ?

*Let $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\}$, where $x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ for some prime $p > 0$ be coordinates of a $n-1$-degree polynomial $f$ that is not known. Suppose that $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\}$ and $x_n$ are known, but $y_n$ is not known. The distribution of possible values of $y_n$ is uniform, so that the distribution of possible polynomials $f$ is also uniform.*

Comment: You might be interested in [lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks for the tip I will take a look at it ... But is the statement true ?

Comment: What is the probability space? Otherwise, what do you mean with "uniform distribution"? And why should it not be possible that $y_n$ can take any available value?